# JQuery DIV popup while making the webpage dimmer

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have the following CSS:

```
.faq {
    position: absolute;
    border: 3px double #078800;
    background: #ECFFEB;
    left: 480px;
    width: 550px;
    z-index: 99999;
}
#showFAQ {
    cursor: pointer;
    color: #018125;
}
```

JQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#showFAQ').click(function(){
        $('.faq').show().css("top", "400px").animate({top: 1150}, 300);
    });

    $('.sButton').click(function(){
        $('.faq').fadeOut('slow');
    });
});
```

HTML:

```
<span id="showFAQ">FAQ</span>

...

<div class=faq style='display: none'>
    <table border=0 cellPadding=8 cellSpacing=8 width=100%>
        <tr>
            <td colSpan=2 align=center style="font-family: Verdana, Arial; color: #078800; font-weight: bold; font-size: 18px;">Frequently Aasked Questions</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>1. Do I have to complete the entire "Your Information" section?</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="padding-left:50px;">Yes, all information inside the "Your Information" is required to successfully complete the exam. Failure to do so will result in having to retake the exam from scratch.</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>2. What if my browser crashes or the page exits and I was in the middle of the exam?</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="padding-left:50px;">Unfortunately, at this time there is no way to save the session. You will have to retake the exam from the start. We are working on fixing that and will update everyone on when it goes in effect.</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>3. Can I retake the exam multiple times?</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="padding-left:50px;">Yes, but only the first one will count. If for any reason, you needed to take it more than once, please email HR and let them know why and they will reach out to you to with resolution.</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>4. I pressed the "Submit Answers" button and now the button shows "Processing..." but I can't press it anymore?</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="padding-left:50px;">There is an error control put in place to ensure every question is answered before submitting the exam. Please ensure all questions have been answered and then the "Processing..." button will change back to "Submit Answers" which is clickable.</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>5. I did everything as per instruction, but I can't still submit the exam.</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="padding-left:50px;">Please reach out to our Helpdesk at x2000 for further troubleshooting steps to assist in completing the exam.</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colSpan=2 align=center><input class=sButton type=button value="Close Window" /></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

What I am looking to do is once the popup appears, i want the entire page to dim out so the popup gets the user's attention. I know there are others out there but I decided to do my own without needing much coding.

I want to use the following image which has 45% opacity:
[image: Fade BG]

I want to put the image using repeat-x and repeat-y to cover the entire page directly below the popup so the user can still see the page but the popup stands out. Once I close the popup, i would like the image to fadeout to display the webpage.

Comment: z-index: 909090909090909090909090909090; ?!?!?!?!?!? The max value is probably signed 32-bit values (−2147483648 to +2147483647)

Comment: Well its for testing only...

Comment: @watson yeah lol wut.... for OP, just have a div in your body with gigantic size  in relative position and your popup inside with absolute position or whatever positionning you prefer. make its Z-index to 999 when it is visible and -999 when it's hidden. don't play with 90909090909......... and provide a fiddle plz :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just create a modal 'underlay' for your faq div, like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/P2BfF/1/

```
 <div class="modal" style="display:none;"></div>

 .modal {
    width: 100000px;
    height: 100000px;
    background-color: #ccc;
    position:absolute;
    opacity: 0.2;
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

Note: I set the width and height really high because you have the FAQ popup animating its position.

then you add this to your toggle in the JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#showFAQ').click(function(){
        $('.modal').show();
        $('.faq').show().css("top", "400px").animate({top: 1150}, 300);
    });

    $('.sButton').click(function(){
        $('.faq').fadeOut('slow');
        $('.modal').hide();
    }); 
});
```

Comment: How do I change the .CSS() to be CENTERED on the page?

Comment: do you mean, how do you get the FAQ popup to be centered on the page?

Comment: Check out this link : http://jsfiddle.net/P2BfF/2/, I have removed the div.modal and added a box-shadow to your faq container instead. It's got a huge spread on it to give you that underlay effect. Also, I set the left and right margins on the faq css to 25% to center it for you. You may need to tweak it a little, but there is the general functionality for you.

Comment: I decided to go with something which I was able to modify to fit my need but thank you for the assistance. Answer accepted.

Comment: Ok, as long as you're up and running. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Create a blanket div the full size of the window, styled how you wish. Give it a z-index greater than your page. Create a new div with your pop-up, and give it a z-index greater than your blanket.

```
#blanket {
  z-index:1000;
  position:fixed;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  opacity:0.45;
/* Other styling here */
}
#popup {
  z-index:1001;
/* other styling here */
}
```

Comment: add the background-image: url(myopactiybackground.png); ? Should i set #blanket to display: none?

Comment: The blanket can be turned on and off as you need. display:none will hide it initially. Use $('#blanket').show() or similar to turn it on.